# Where does mass go?

Tags: agar.io

In [agar.io](http://agar.io), sources of mass are abundant. The little pellets of nutrition spawn frequently. The problem is that there are no places for mass to go - which it must do otherwise the game would run out of space. Even when people log out, their cell remains stationary until it is eaten. I'm assuming then that mass must be lost in one of the following situations:

- When splitting (via space)
- When popped (via a spike)

Is this the case? If so, how much of my total mass is lost when this happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [Ardaozkal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/87186/ardaozkal) his comment I was able to do some research.

There are a couple of reasons why the game never runs out of space,

- When just going around not collecting any orbs you seem to lose a bit off mass. The amount of mass you lose seems to be bigger if you have a lot.
- When pressing <kbd>W</kbd> you shoot out a bit off mass, picking it back up will not give you back the amount you lost.

*Splitting up or hitting a spike does not seem to make you lose anything other then your shape.*

Comment: Consuming a virus (the spike) is suppose to actually increase your mass, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You eject 13 mass every time you press w or, on the mobile version, click the target button, but your cell loses 18 mass, so self feeding, or ejecting mass and then eating it again, will cause you to lose mass, not stay the same. You can eat viruses when you are split into 16 pieces, and you gain 100 mass every time you eat a virus, even if you aren't split into 16 pieces. You can eat viruses by having 2 cells that can eat the virus and running one of them into the virus, so you end up with 16 cells, and you can then go around eating viruses, but you have to be careful, since other players can eat your smaller pieces, and then eat you completely. You can make new viruses by ejecting seven times into an existing virus, and a new one will be shot out in the opposite direction of the last pellet you shot out. This is very useful for splitting bigger players so that you can eat them. Try using keyword skins, which means entering a name like Earth, which will give you a Earth skin. There are a lot more of these keyword skins, and you can make your own skin it the store or other places. It costs 90 DNA, though, so try to save up. Hope this helps!